# Unable to store data in variable from Serial.read()

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I have a relay and bluetooth module connected to Arduino Uno. I send data such as digit 1 to the bluetooth module and I view it in the Serial Monitor. If I send 1 from serial monitor I get 4910 printed.

I would like to turn on the relay and have it stay on until I send a different digit. However, in my code below it doesnt work, the relay doesnt stay on.

Only, if I put the digital.write under **while(Serial.available())** it works.

```
const int ledPin =  11;
int relayOn;

void setup() {

  //initialize serial port for logs
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  while (Serial.available()) {

      Serial.println("Data: ");

      Serial.println(Serial.read());

      if(Serial.read())
      {
        relayOn = Serial.parseInt(); 
      }

      while (relayOn > 1)
      {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

      }

    }

}
```

Comment: You can make it easier by using commands which are only 1 character. For example '1' or 'A' to turn it on and '0' or 'a' to turn it off. Start with a good description of the commands and the communication. A Serial.read() read a character, and you can not read it again with another Serial.read().

Comment: But can I store the data from Serial.read() inside a variable without having to keep sending the data continuously, I want the relay to stay on until I send different data 0 or 1 etc

Comment: @condo1234 You are rushing ahead. First describe the data/commands that you transmit. Do you want, for example, make it hard for yourself and be able to send the number "15"? Then step by step write it in code, if possible without the parseInt.

Comment: Now I am sending number 5 to turn on relay and 0 to turn off. Would it make a difference to send 1 to turn on? I also tried to assign variable relayOn in my code with Serial.read() and define it as char, but still didn't match. Do you have any example code I am a little confused with how to keep the relay on after I send data from bluetooth

Comment: what is the value of `relayOn` when you input a `1` and and also when you input a  `0`?

Comment: @jsotola when I send 1 I get 0 when doing Serial.printIn(relayOn)

Comment: Serial.println(Serial.read()); removes the data from the serial buffer.  if(Serial.read()) will be always false

Comment: Actually  the second "Serial.read()" will always return -1, this should be interpreted as true.

Comment: @Dorian you are correct!! That was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is "5\n" with '\n' as line ending setting in Serial Monitor.

In the code you have first `Serial.println(Serial.read());`. It will read and print the '5'. Then you have `if(Serial.read())`. It will read the '\n'. It is not 0 so the next line is `relayOn = Serial.parseInt()`. It will find no input and times out returning 0.

if you want to use parseInt():

```
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial.print("Data: ");
    relayOn = Serial.parseInt(); 
    Serial.println(relayOn);
    if (relayOn > 1) {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense, I will try send with 1 and 0 and see if that works

Comment: Sorry I meant I already tried Serial.parseInt() and that outputs 0 when output relayOn in serial monitor, tried the same as your above code

Comment: it is not about what number you send, but how you read it. the answer explains the 0

Comment: I have changed to send 1 and used your code with Serial.parseInt() and when I output Serial.printIn(relayOn) I get 0 and Serial.printIn(Serial.read()) I get -1.

Comment: replace your loop() function with the loop() function from my answer

Comment: Ok I did that and now it outputs 0 if I send 1

Comment: I used in void setup() { Serial.begin(9600);}. In serial monitor I use 9600, its strange when I enter 1 from serial I get output 4910 everytime inside Serial.printIn(Serial.read())

Comment: 49 is ascii code of the character '1'. 10 is ascii code of  the character '\n' (new line)

Comment: So, what do I do to make the relay turn on and stay on and then turn off when I send different character... that is all I need to do ... any code ideas? thanks for your help so far. I am sending a 1 from the Serial monitor and android app, seems like both not sending an integer

Comment: So in if statement do I check for string, i.e. if (relayOn == '1') instead? And do I change relayOn from int to char?

Comment: It's not fair to delete an answer with usefull comments from OP then after the issue was solved to show up with it. The answer wasn'there when I made my comments.

Comment: @Dorian, I am really sorry. I deleted the answer, because OP indicated that the problem is something else and the answer didn't solve it. I wrote first a similar comment then yours. It was 3th or 4th comment and was totally ignored by OP and other commenters. Then I wrote the answer and deleted the comment. Then the answer seemed to be off...

Comment: It was at least part of the solution, I would upvoted your answer if I would find-it as i did with kuskus's answer posted shortly after my comment to let op know that it really has an issue there.

Comment: @Dorian, sorry. it was a bad decision

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like (not tested):

```
void loop() {
 if(Serial.available()){
   input = Serial.parseInt();
   Serial.print("Data: ");
   Serial.println(input);
   if(input == 1){
      digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
   }
   else if(input == 2{
      digitalWrite(RELAY, LOW);
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
   }
 }
}
```

don't forget to declare input variable, use 1 to turn on, 2 off :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using serial interrupt in arduino

```
void loop() {
}

void serialEvent() 
{
  while (Serial.available()) 
    {
       char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
      Serial.print("Data: ");
      Serial.println(inChar);
       if (inChar == '1') 
        {
              digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
              break;
        }
       else
        {
              digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
              break;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: it is not an interrupt. https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/5755ddea49fa69d6c505c772ebee5af5078e2ebf/cores/arduino/main.cpp#L45

Comment: but is acts as serial interrupt in arduino